# Get count and sum for different purchase types on same table/colum

Tags: mysql

I have a "transaction" table that has the following columns

```
ID    TIMESTAMP    USER ID    DESCRIPTION    AMOUNT    REF_ID    TYPE
```

The description column contains the payment platform used for example "STRIPE-ch_1745". We currently have 4 platforms all described in the reference as in the example above. What I want is to get the payment platform, the total amount processed by the platform and the count of transactions. Like this

```
Platform    Amount    Count
Stripe      100,000   78
iOS         78,000    50
```

My current code only gives me these values for one platform, I've been unable to structure this properly to give me the desired result. I assumed I needed nested select statements, so I wrote the code in that manner

```
SELECT txn_count, sum
FROM
(SELECT count(*) AS txn_count, sum(`transaction`.`amount`) AS `sum`
FROM `transaction`
WHERE (`transaction`.`type` = 'credit'
   AND (`transaction`.`description` like 'stripe%')
   AND str_to_date(concat(date_format(`transaction`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') = str_to_date(concat(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'))) t1
```

What this gives me right now is

```
Txn Count    Sum
311          501,000
```

Would appreciate some help on how to get the expected table

Comment: You should review mysql aggregate functions.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : ( edited to remove the reference part, assuming the reference is always separated by the platform by '-' )

```
SELECT 
LEFT(t.description,LOCATE('-',t.description) - 1) as 'Platform',
SUM(t.amount) as 'Amount',
COUNT(*) as 'Count'
FROM transaction t
GROUP BY Platform
```

Comment: When taking t.description, I don't need every unique value (t.description includes platform+reference so it's always unique). So this might not work

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. One quick question, what's the function of '-1' in this line (t.description,LOCATE('-',t.description) - 1)?

Comment: This is because locate starts at index 1, not 0